# Dada una cantidad de troncos, el programa debe indicar el tamaño máximo de la base de la pila a construir y la cantidad de troncos que sobran

Tags: javascript, html, lógica

```
var troncos = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese numero de troncos'))

function madera(n1) {

    let maximo = 0
    let resto = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {

        maximo += i
            
        }
    }
    console.log(maximo)


madera(troncos)
```

Tengo el siguiente problema
Dada una cantidad de troncos
el programa debe indicar el tamaño máximo de la base de la pila a construir y la cantidad de troncos que sobran.

Se me ocurrio ir recorriendo la cantidad de troncos (variable troncos) e ir sumando por fila de la piramide hasta que se alcanze el maximo posible pero estoy trancado y no se como poder realizarlo. Capaz hay una manera mas simple

Ejemplo: se ingresa 15, se indica tamaño 5 y sobran 0

Ejemplo: se ingresa 8, se indica tamaño 3 y sobran 2

Ejemplo: se ingresa 1, se indica tamaño 1 y sobran 0

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En una pirámide de troncos la cantidad de troncos de la base es igual al número de filas que tiene.

Para resolver el problema utilizo 2 funciones recursivas:

- totalTroncos(base): retorna la cantidad de troncos de una pirámide que tiene n (parámetro) troncos en la fila base.
- piramideTroncos(filas, cantidadTroncos): calcula el total de troncos de la pirámide (a partir de la cantidad de troncos especificada por el usuario), el total de troncos de la fila base y la cantidad de troncos sobrantes (la muestra por consola).

```
/**
 * Calcula el total de troncos de la pirámide
 * en función del número de troncos de la base.
 *
 * @param int base //total de troncos de la fila base o total de filas.
 * @return int //total del troncos de la pirámide.
 */
function totalTroncos(base) {
  if(base == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return totalTroncos(base - 1) + base;
  }
}

/**
 * Calcula el total de troncos de la pirámide, el total de troncos de la 
 * fila base y la cantidad de troncos sobrantes.
 *
 * @param int filas //total de troncos de la fila base o total de filas.
 * @param int cantidadTroncos //cantidad de troncos especificada por el usuario.
 * @return int //la cantidad de troncos que tendra la pirámide.
 */
function piramideTroncos(filas, cantidadTroncos) {
  let totalPorFilas = totalTroncos(filas);

  if (totalPorFilas == cantidadTroncos) {
    console.log("Tamaño de la pirámide: "  + totalPorFilas + " troncos, total troncos en la base: " + filas + ", sobran: 0 troncos.");

    return totalPorFilas;

  } else if (totalPorFilas > cantidadTroncos) {
    let totalPorFilasAnterior = totalTroncos(filas - 1);

    console.log("Tamaño de la pirámide: " + totalPorFilasAnterior + " troncos, total troncos en la base: " + (filas - 1) + ", sobran: " + (cantidadTroncos - totalPorFilasAnterior) + " troncos.");

    return totalPorFilas;
  }

  piramideTroncos(filas + 1, cantidadTroncos);
}


//Cantidad de troncos ingresada por el usuario
var cantidadTroncos = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese número de troncos.'));

piramideTroncos(1, cantidadTroncos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboracion, podrias decirme por que el 1 en piramideTroncos(1, cantidadTroncos)?

Comment: De nada! Empieza probando con una pirámide de una fila y va sumando filas hasta que haya la pirámide correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Visualmente: con 8 troncos se indica 3 y sobran 2 es porque entran 6 troncos con una base de 3

```
1
23
456
---
78 <- me faltan troncos y se me cae
```

( troncos número 7 y 8 sobran porque no llegan a formar una base estable )

viendo cuantos troncos entran por línea tenemos que hay 1 tronco, 2 troncos, 3 troncos y si seguimos armando pilas con mas troncos la secuencia es la de números naturales 1 a n.

Viéndolo de otro modo la suma de la cantidad de troncos por fila nos da la cantidad de troncos total en la pila o triángulo que se forma.

```
1 tronco + 2 troncos + 3 troncos = 6 troncos
si tengo 8 me sobran 2
```

Si encontramos una fórmula que nos diga cuanto suman en total la secuencia de los números entre 1 y n ( n es igual a 3 en este caso ) podríamos saber cuanto es el mínimo de troncos para cada n ( n es igual a 3 en este caso y es la cantidad de troncos en la base ) y si este mínimo de troncos necesarios lo restamos de la cantidad de troncos que nos dan tenemos el problema resuelto.

Por suerte esa fórmula existe y mepa que la movida va por este lado https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_triangular

> Un número triangular cuenta objetos dispuestos en un triángulo equilátero. El n-ésimo número triangular es el número de puntos en la disposición triangular con n puntos en un lado, y es igual a la suma de los n números naturales de 1 a n, siendo por convención, el 1 el primer número triangular.

Ahora para encontrar el mínimo número triangular necesitamos la reversa, en la wiki español no aparece pero para no hacer mucha matemática vamos a la wiki en inglés donde si aparece como ["raíz triangular"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers)

Usando esa fórmula, calculamos la raiz triangular del total de troncos, nos quedamos con la parte entera ( no hay medios troncos ) y así obtenemos la cantidad mínima de troncos (enteros) que hacen falta en la base para armar un triángulo.

Los troncos que sobran los obtenemos de restarle al total el "número triangular" de la base entera que obtuvimos ( la cantidad de troncos que usamos )

```js
// https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_triangular
const numTriangular = function(n) {
  t = n * (n + 1) / 2
  return t
}

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers
const raizTriangular = function(x) {
  n = (Math.sqrt(8 * x + 1) - 1) / 2;
  return n;
}
const calculaPilaDeTroncos = function(x) {
  let base = Math.floor(raizTriangular(x))
  let sobran = x - numTriangular(base)
  console.log(`con ${x} troncos, la base es de ${base} y sobran ${sobran} `)
}

calculaPilaDeTroncos(15);
calculaPilaDeTroncos(8);
calculaPilaDeTroncos(1);
```